# Passing an array of struct to function changes size of array

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

I have a struct:

```
struct Thing {
    int id;
}
```

Then I create an array of `Thing`s:

```
struct Thing *a;
a = (struct Thing *) malloc(sizeof(struct Thing));
a->id = 1;

struct Thing *b;
b = (struct Thing *) malloc(sizeof(struct Thing));
b->id = 2;

struct Thing *array[] = {a,b};
```

I check the size of the array and is 2.
I check the size of array by:

```
printf("%d",sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
```

I also have a function that takes in an array of Things:

```
void function(struct Thing *array[]) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Then I pass in the array to function:

```
function(array);
```

Inside the function, the size of the array is 1.
Can someone point to me where did I go wrong and why is the size of the array 1 inside of the function?

Comment: please read the C FAQ http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Comment: or of [what is array decaying?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432)

Comment: @KarthikT I found my solution from ZhangYuan at a comment below.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass an array of any kind to a function, it *decays* to a pointer to the first element of this array.

```
void function(struct Thing *array[]) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Is just syntactic sugar for

```
void function(struct Thing** array) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: That explains why only the 1st element remains.

Comment: @drum, both elements are still there, 2nd element can be accessed as `array[1]`. It is just that the data type has changed from array to pointer, and thus the behavior of `sizeof` with it.

Comment: No, both elements remain, but the pointer points only to the beginning of the array! You should be able to access the second index in the funtion without SEGFAULT.

Answer (score 1):

Your array-definition

```
struct Thing *array[] = {a,b};
```

should be

```
struct Thing array[] = {a,b};
```

then pass it to the function; the function should be declared

```
void function(struct Thing *array, int count) {
//do stuff
}
```

so you can pass the bounds of the array.

Comment: `a` and `b` are pointers to struct and you are suggesting to initialize an array of structs with pointers to structs, how is that going to work?

Comment: `struct Thing array[] = {*a,*b}`;

Comment: @ZhangYuan: Thank you! That was exactly the solution to my problem! You should post the answer and I'll accept it.